# Including $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to load files outside of wordpress installation doesn't work remotely

Tags: paths

I have built a wordpress site locally in a directory /blog I have other site files that are at the web root that I need to access in the WordPress installation, css, js etc.

Locally I included the files by:

```
<style>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'css/site-style.css'); ?> 
</style>
```

For reasons out of my control we inject the styles into the head instead of wp_enqueue_styles.. I know gross

This worked fine locally, but now that I have deployed the files remotely it no longer works. If I echo the path out I receive the proper file path. Is there a function or way so that I can access the files both locally and remotely outside of the wordpress installation?

thanks for your help!

Comment: The title mentioned `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, but your code is using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` ? Have you tried `dirname( ABSPATH )` ? And.. why don't you just move the assets to the theme active folder?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I was trying some things and forgot to change my code back. I tried your suggestion but it did not output. I can not move the files around as the blog should depend on the root of the site not the other way around.

Comment: Perhaps you're just missing a `/` as in `/css/site-style.css`. But you should remember, relative paths in the CSS/JS files won't work as expected. So you might better off link to the files than including their content from your WordPress installation directory. E.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="full/absolute/path/to/file">`